# Как работать с Cookie в Android + php?

Tags: java, android, cookie

На удивление не нашел ответа или урока на русском языке по этой теме

1. На сервере php я генерирую куку, как мне её передать и принять в
   java приложении на Android?
2. Где её хранить в приложении?
3. Как она будет подцепляться к запросам?
4. Использую в некоторых запросах библиотеку OKHTTP, как ей сообщить
   о куке?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150089/how-to-handle-cookies-in-httpurlconnection-using-cookiemanager?noredirect=1&lq=1
перейдите по ссылке там ответ на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от библиотеки которую вы используете в качестве http клиента.
Либо куки ручками просить из заголовков, либо они сохранятся в переменную. Аналогично обратно, некоторые либы, такие как впаяна кий http клиент, на сколько я помню это сделают сами если вы не убьете объект с клиентов. Если юзаете что-то вроде natty то ручками передавать в заголовки. 
Так что все зависит от библиотеки.